# How to get back to focus on input element when using JQuery onfocusout or onblur event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to validate the input field value. If it's the wrong to value, the focus should be retained in the same input field when I used either on blur and `onfocusout`. Please help me out.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#txt_fname").on("focusout", (function(evnt){
  if ($(this).val() != "name"){
   event.preventDefault();
   //$("#txt_fname").focus().trigger('focusin');
   $("#txt_fname").focus();
   return false;
  }
 })
 );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_fname" name="txt_fname" value="" placeholder="Enter a First name" maxlength="10">
<input type="text" id="txt_lname" name="txt_lname" value="" placeholder="Enter a Last name" maxlength="10">
```

The snippet is working fine, but in my localhost using `xampp`, it's not working. Even, I changed the Jquery version too:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't know, what is the issue behind this. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: Try debugging the process using `console.log` and see what is happening in every step - is the "focusout" works as expected? Are the selectors working as well?

Comment: Devis and Alon
No, I didn't get any errors in console and tried with console.log, i am getting the test msg in console.

Answer (score 1):

Found a typo in your code which probably caused the issue, in the word `evnt`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt_fname").on("focusout", (function(evnet){ //you typed "evnt" by mistake
        if ($(this).val() != "name"){
            event.preventDefault();
            //$("#txt_fname").focus().trigger('focusin');
            $("#txt_fname").focus();
            return false;
        }
    })
    );
});
```

Tested in my localhost, works like a charm.

### Update

Since the OP said that he is using Firefox, while I tested it in Chrome, I realized that maybe it is a browser related issue.

After a bit of digging, I realized that if you focus out from an element and right after that you try to focus in again by using a script, for some reason (maybe a bug?) Firefox doesn't have enough time to blur and focus again.

By using JavaScript `setTimeout` and setting the time to a pretty low value (I used 10 milliseconds in the example) and putting the focus function inside of the timeout callback, I managed to solve the issue.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#txt_fname").focus();
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your updates! but still, the issue persist... It's strange for me...

Comment: @RameshMoorthy Can you show me your full code? Use pastebin for example

Comment: Yes, I put my code pastebin for your review.
https://pastebin.com/C5vZRYfg

Comment: @RameshMoorthy I tried the same code in my WampServer localhost and it works. Something seems very odd, what browser are you using? Maybe a different browser will give a different result?

Comment: I am using Firfox browser, Is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: @RameshMoorthy solved :) I updated my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will help:

```
    $(document).on("focusout", "#txt_fname", function()
    { 
           if ($(this).val() != "name")
          {
                 $("#txt_fname").focus();
                 return false;
           }
    })
```

Comment: I am using FireFox browser. Its working in Chrome only.